# ionic serve and ionic build work ok, ionic build --prod creates failing code

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dependency-injection, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I have a PWA app that works well when I run `ionic serve`.
When I run `ionic build`, I get a browser version (in www) that works as well also.
But when I build for production `ionic build --prod`, the build runs to completion but the code (in www folder) fails to render with an error that gives no clue how to debug.  How do I debug this?
Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[n -> n]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
Error: StaticInjectorError[n -> n]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[n -> n]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
    at t.get (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1
    at t (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at t.get (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1
    at t (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at t.get (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at lo (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at t.get (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at lo (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1)
    at polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.8c77a03c89ac993f4bf3.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1)
    at g (polyfills.b22498af0f647703dfdb.js:1)
```

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.10.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.1
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.3.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.15.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.7.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: can you try ng build --prod ?

Comment: I tried ng build --prod with same result.

Comment: I built the Android version using `ionic cordova build --release android` and that works fine too.  I'm building a PWA version for browser ie not hybrid for mobile.

Comment: What platform Android, iOS etc? Maybe it;'s because you didn't specify that on command line **Platform** "No **provider** for n!" https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build vs https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/build - Maybe `ionic build --prod` instead? Cordova only comes into play when doing mobile right. Have not done Ionic 4 PWA myself yet. But cordova is the foundation for mobile. Let me know if that solved it.

Comment: It was working under ionic 3.  I recently upgraded to ionic 4.

Comment: I'm stuck on Ionic 3 myself still ATM. But cordova in the command line is what stood out and the fact that platform was what it was objecting to. Did a quick Google to verify my suspicions on CLI syntax.

Comment: I ran `ionic build --prod` and that generates the code in www folder that fails.

Comment: Problem solved.  There was a service module missing from the providers: array.  Not very obvious as the name bore no resemblance to the error message.  Ionic serve some how gets around the problem but the ng build --prod does not.